# Zend Lucene and hyphens - searching part numbers

Tags: lucene

I have set up Zend Lucene to search products_name and part_number.

This works well, however there are issues with hyphenated part numbers.

For example, if I have the part number: 5130193-00

This will return any part number with '00' at the end.

How can I make Lucene only return the exact part number?

I am using Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer::setDefault(new Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer_Common_TextNum_CaseInsensitive()); when indexing and searching (CaseInsensitive does not work, but that's another issue) and the part numbers are indexed as Text.

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping dash with a slash: `part_number:5130193\-00`.

More information is available [here](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/2_9_1/queryparsersyntax.html) (see *Escaping Special Characters*).

Comment: Thanks, will try it.  I saw similar elsewhere, but it indicated using a forward slash (did not work).  I actually tried this: $word = Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_QueryParser::escape($word);  This did not work either.

Comment: I tried the backslash - no change.  The search will bring up anything with '00'.  I even tried re-indexing, making part_number a Keyword.  Still no change.  It appears that Lucene just wants to split the search query at the hyphen and search both halves.

Comment: Reindexing as keyword was actually good idea. You can also try querying it like so: `part_number:"5130193-00"`.

Comment: How dumb that I can't answer my own question.

Comment: The solution for me was to modify the appropriate analyser file nextToken() method, in my case TextNum.php

Change the preg_match to:

    preg_match('/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+/', $this->_input, $match, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, $this->_position)

This allows both hyphens and underscores. After re-indexing this worked fine, only giving an exact match result for part numbers like 5130193-00

Comment: when I originally indexed, I expected that the entire string would be treated as text and indexed as such, not realizing that hyphens were completely ignored.  My solution above worked a treat, forcing both hyphens and underscores as part of a single index record.